# Android killing Activity

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

In my Application at one point I open the setting of the phone (for the user to enable wifi or data network) like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

When I return to my Activity though `onCreate()` is called again? I would expect `onStart()`->`onResume()` to be called. But since that's the way it is I guess Android killed it for memory purposes. What troubles me is that `onDestroy()` was never called is this normal? can `onCreate()` of an Activity to be called twice, without `onDestroy()` having been called not even once?

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    Log.e("onDestroy","Im destroyed");

    try{
        if(pois!=null)
            pois.clear();
        pois=null;
    }catch(Exception e){
        ;
    }

    super.onDestroy();
    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.RootView));
    System.gc();
}


@Override
protected void onPause(){

    super.onPause();
    restore();

}
```

Comment: have you called finish() after this line ?

Comment: no, was I supposed to?

Comment: did you called onResume() in your activity ?

Comment: post more code ... since it is difficult to say this way

Comment: your comments are wrong and confusing. You should not be calling either of those methods.

Comment: the thing is that onDestroy is never called and when I return from settings onCreate is called instead of onResume

Comment: Take a look at the picture to undsterstand the logic.  I dont see why its not being called. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: IF you will not call startActivity and Just destroying seting Intent it is not possible that it will call onCreate..
try this command, it will tell you the activity in stack
adb shell <enter> 
dumpsys activity | grep -i

Comment: I know this picture, and for me it's really weird. I never see though the I'm destroyed message

Comment: If you never see the destroyed message.. it is never being destroyed. So OnStart would not be called. As it would go to `Paused` State, then back to `Resumed` State.

Comment: Yes I agree though onCreate() is called

Answer (score 0):

After `startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));` don't call `finish()`. If you call finish() then your activity will be destroyed. So just call startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)); and in settings if u click back press without recreating the activity your app will be opened. There **onStart()** and **onResume()** will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Once onCreate method is invoked it cannot be called again without destroying it. 
On your code when you call on create method and then opens the setting of your phone, your app automatically calls onpause state and after you get back to your app doing the setting you needed onresume state gets called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is working quite fine the way you want, You can also try  from  terminal to know the activities in your app's stack

```
adb shell <enter>
dumpsys activity | grep -i



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
    Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "OnResume");
    super.onResume();
}
```